# Can SSRS handle really large data sets better than Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I need to create report using SQL Server data from couple million records.  Getting this error in Excel any way to resolve this?  Or should I switch to SSRS which I don't know if it's better for handling large data sets since I never used it before.

[image]

Comment: I never understood the need for BIG reports.   No human can digest that much information.  Your users would be better off with an interactive environment.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I believe the end user both want a report and also the raw data so they can create their own report if needed without having to go through sql server.

Comment: End users skills have skyrocketed over the years, but it is still risky.   Let's assume they accept the risk of erroneous results/conclusions (Execution Risk)... you now have working data in the wild for anyone to consume (Reputation Risk)

Comment: Load the data into a datamodel in Excel and use Power Query. Then as long as the final output does not exceed approx 1 millions you'll be fine. I produce workbooks for some of my superusers that contains 10 millions rows of data which they use in  several different worksheets via pivot tables, dashboards etc, aggregating the data in different ways as their requirements change. The pivot tables for example, rather exceed a few thousand rows as the data is aggregated.

Comment: yes ill look into this data model thingy looks promising.

Comment: The Data model in Excel is called Power Pivot.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-pivot-overview-and-learning-f9001958-7901-4caa-ad80-028a6d2432ed